# Dropzone maxfilesize in kb

Tags: php, dropzone.js

How can i limit the maxFilesize in KB?.

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 5, //in MB
    init: function() {
      this.on("uploadprogress", function(file, progress) {
        console.log("File progress", progress);
      });
    }
  }
```

I want to limit the file size in KB

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what isn't working? 5 MB ~= 5000 KB, or rather 5 KB = .005 MB. So set `maxFilesize: .005` Or you could set a variable above `var maxSizeKb = 5;` and then set `maxFilesize: maxSizeKb / 1000`.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones is the minFilesize option available? how can I set minimum file size?.

Comment: https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/configuration-options it doesn't look like that's an option, which is surprising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works for me. thank you @WOUNDEDStevenJones.

```
var maxfile = 100;//in KB
var maxfileresult = maxfile/1000;
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    maxFilesize: maxfileresult ,
    init: function() {
      this.on("uploadprogress", function(file, progress) {
        console.log("File progress", progress);
      });
    }
  }
```